# Missing constraint warning for Barrier - Bug?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I get the missing constraints warning on the `Barrier`, which has been added to the (now stable) version `1.1.0` of the `ConstraintLayout`.

> This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints

However, a `Barrier` to my knowledge doesn't use any constraints and I don't think it's even possible to add them

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Barriers typically go to the end or beginning of a view. Guidelines are the ones that have no constraints

Comment: But barriers take either the full width or the full height and the other dimension is defined by the views it contains.

Comment: Show some code so that we can understand more

Answer (score 22):

If you have something like `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="123dp"` or `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="384dp"` defined on the barrier just remove it and the warning will go away.

Comment: Would this be considered a bug? Or is this how it's supposed to be?

Comment: The view can't be constrained, just because the layout editor had a flag that should have no bearing on the layout, doesn't mean it should throw an error telling you to do the impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Are you Getting this type of error

[image]

Try adding barrier in this way

```
<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1,view2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to specify the **barrierDirection** parameter:

```
    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="end"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1,view2" />
```

Specifying a "barrierDirection" to end will notify the barrier to position at the end of the widest view speicified in the referenced ids.

But at design time, your designer might not refresh the barrier position... like in my case:
[barrier constraint not calculated on designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YsBN.png)

**EDIT:**
After Cleaning up cache and migrating to ConstraintLayout '2.0.0-alpha3' the Barrier is shown properly at design time.